# fetchmail/sendmail/procmail alternative

Tags: email-server, sendmail, procmail, email

is there a program out there that can download mail from an imap account to a local machine for local reading with a program like mutt? I'm finding the whole fetchmail/sendmail/procmail pipeline setup to be a bit much, but I still want to use the maildir or mbox format that unix is designed around. I also don't want to use the built in imap code mutt has because I don't want to have mutt running constantly just to check my mail.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no alternative. The only thing you can do is to eliminate Sendmail. Fetchmail and procmail is everything you need. See this excellent post on how to accomplish this: http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/97/using-fetchmail-and-procmail-for-maildir-style-storage-from-a-pop3-account/

**Important edit:**

There is an alternative called [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/).

Comment: `getmail` was the solution for me. It doesn't clear the 'unread' flag after retrieving messages from the server, whereas `fetchmail` does.

Answer (score 2):

[There is a very good and easy-to-use IMAP synchronization tool called offlineimap](https://github.com/nicolas33/offlineimap).